# Changing the text inside my button that uses an ngFor

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

In my NativeScript app, I am trying to use a *ngFor to display the number of players that the user chose on a separate screen. This will say "Player 1, Player 2, etc." Then, when they click that button to select a player, I want to be able to change the text that says "Player ..." to say the player's name that's chosen. As you'll see, I tried using `document.getElementById` to choose the element but wasn't quite sure how to change the text once I got there.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. I've simplified it so that instead of reading in the user's input (size), it's just set to 6. Also, I don't have the list of players come up or anything and am just trying to change the text of the button to anything at this moment. The rest will be easy once I figure out how to do that.

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=67JcNJ&v=5

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

## It's better to use index to identify the item in ngFor

In `home.component.html`,

```
<Button [text]="(i == this.selectedIndex)? 'Player ' + key + ' is selected' : 'Player ' + key" *ngFor="let key of playersArray; let i = index;" (tap)="selectPlayer(i)"></Button>
```

In `home.component.ts`, add these

```
public selectedIndex = -1;

public selectPlayer(index) {
  this.selectedIndex = index;
}
```

**P.S. Should avoid touching the DOM directly in Angular**

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm guessing document doesn't exist in mobile which is why it doesn't work for you. I would do this:

```
public selectPlayer(id): void {
    this.playersArray[id - 1] = "Player Name";
  //document.getElementById(id + "player").innerText = "Player Name";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply pass the `$event` object to the `tap` event handler and do `event.object.text` to update the button text. But since you have a property binding on the button element, it might change back to actual value from array during a change detection cycle. So `this.playersArray[id - 1] = "Player Name";` could work unless you don't want to change the source array.

`event.object` will be the button which was tapped. It's not a HTML button so you can't use HTML specific properties. Checkout the [Button component](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_button_.button) for all available list of properties.

Also `document.getElementById` is HTML specific, it suppose to be `.getViewById('yourViewId')` from parent view. You might want to go through the basics of {N} components.

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=67JcNJ&v=7)